# What is $ \int_0^{\infty} \left( e^{\frac{\ln x} {x}}-1 \right) dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

As per what I have tried, I don't think that  $ \int\left( e^{\frac{\ln x} {x}} \right) dx$ can be expressed in terms of elementary functions, but then I again I have just started learning integration by myself so i'm not sure.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: According to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E(ln(x)%2Fx)+-+1+from+0+to+infty), the integral diverges and the indefinite integral can't be expressed in terms of standard mathematical functions because $e^{\frac{\ln(x)}{x}} = \sqrt[x]{x}$.

Comment: @Viktor Does that mean I would have to express it in form of a power series?

Comment: @RithikKapoor - You  could, but it's a divergent integral....

Comment: Yeah I understand now

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to find the indefinite integral (which can't be expressed in terms of standard mathematical functions).

Note that $e^t\geq 1+t$ for $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and therefore
$$\int_e^{\infty} \left( e^{\frac{\ln x} {x}}-1 \right) dx\geq 
\int_e^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{x}\, dx\geq \int_e^{\infty} \frac{1}{x}\, dx=+\infty.$$
Moreover 
$$\int_0^{e} \left( e^{\frac{\ln x} {x}}-1 \right) dx$$
is a finite number because the integrand function is continuous and bounded in $(0,1]$ (note that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}e^{\frac{\ln x} {x}}=0$.)

So what may we conclude?